# Webpack file loader configuration for static images

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Hy, 
i have `/images` folder with `/static` sub-directory with some images.

how i can config webpack to make public avaiable images from `images/static` on path `dist/images/image-name.png`, and preserve names?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CopyWebpackPlugin` to copy all the files to required folder of your build.

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'src/images/static', to: './dist/images' }
  ])
  ]
```

Later you you have to import them like this.

```
<img src="path/to/dist/image.png">
```

Otherwise you can use file-loader to make the file URL available for programmtic usage

```
 {
   test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
   loader: "file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]"
 }
```

and your images will be emitted to:

```
dist/images/
```

Later you can import images like this:

```
import url from './file.png'

<img src={url}>
```

Comment: thank you, but that's don't work... i try modify path but no luck. complete config is here: https://gist.github.com/devvtms/ebd08ab829815209b66bc296cf95d437

Comment: @dbvt10 what erros you're getting ? and I'm not sure what is your app folder structure ?

Comment: there is no errors, simply not copied. folder structure in comment: https://gist.github.com/devvtms/ebd08ab829815209b66bc296cf95d437

Comment: Do the following in output : path.resolve(__dirname,  'dist')

Comment: same... files not copied... :(

Comment: what if the folder is created, but webpack overwite his later with file-loader? that cant happen?

Comment: see please line:8... *facepalm

Comment: Glad to hear your issue is fixed